# Ubuntu 15.10 has kernel version: 4.2.0-23-generic. So

Tags: graphics, ati, gpu-driver, grub-legacy, additional-drivers

Ubuntu 15.10 has kernel version: 4.2.0-23-generic [image]

and ATI legacy drivers for HD 4xxx series cards support upto kernel version up to 3.4
[image]

So does it mean, my old ATI HD4670 is useless on ubuntu 15.10? o.o

Comment: I would take the free driver, because normally older hardware is better supported by FOS. But if you really want the CCC, just test it. It looks like a new clean install, so it doesn't matter if it is not working.

Comment: but how>? 15.10 has kernel version higher than 3.4. :/

Comment: The open source driver is already included in Ubuntu.

Comment: So having an older graphics card is pointless. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Download the driver and extract it. Open a terminal and type

```
chmod u+x amd-driver*.run
sudo ./amd-driver*.run
```

Now it should install the driver, of course it could be, that it's not reaching the requirements (kernel < 3.4).

It would help for all people to answer your question if you say what you have already done, how experienced you are with linux, is it a clean installation,... and so on. The more we know about your problem the better we can help. (I am not only referencing to you. Other people may also learn from my last sentence).

Comment: I am new to ubuntu/Linux.